# copy jenkins job artifact to right destination

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, artifacts

I've setup two project with jenkins, the first is handled by an agent that builds a asp.net mvc project and then publish it on local file system in a folder that is called publish/customername.

the second job run on customer machine and copy the artifact folder in the application directory and restart iis.

The problem is that when i copy the files it replicate the directory structure like

> c:/webs/vhost/project/publish/customername

instead what i want to achieve is to copy all files in

> c:/webs/vhost/project

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your Problem ? Can you be a little more specific, is it a Jenkins Problem or what is not working ? "i copy the files it replicate the directory structure like" did you copy it or is it in a pipeline job ?

Comment: basically the problem is that my build process produces an artifact in publish/customername/**/*.* and i cannot archive artifact only getting the **/*.* part it archives the full publish/customername/**/*.*